# convert string to array of byte then write to bin file

Tags: arrays, string, delphi, byte

Hello i want to convert string to array of bytes then save the bytes at position in hex format to bin file

When I open the binary file using a hex editor and I search for the selected position there is a date example 21-01-2020 so i want to replace it by today's date. Via a TEdit.Text or via a TDateTimePicker or a function that returns to current system date and write directly to the selected offset the desired value.

I'm using this code already found in StackOverflow but it only writes one character
I want to write for example  date from edit1.text to bin file at position x

here's the code :

```
procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
  fs: TFileStream;
  Buff: array of byte;
   begin

    // Set length of buffer and initialize buffer to zeros
       SetLength(Buff, 10);
      FillChar(Buff[0], Length(Buff), #0); // this will write 0 to 10 bytes 
    fs := TFileStream.Create('F:\test\file.bin', fmOpenWrite);
   try
   fs.Position := $15c20;                 // Set to starting point of write
   fs.Write(Buff[0], Length(Buff));   // Write bytes to file
   finally
  fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: As per your code, there's no text to write, only zeroes. Could you please share how it gets the string and a desired outcome?

Comment: Please confirm: Do you want to write the ASCII codes (Or unicode) to the file at the specified position? For example if you have the string 'ABC' do you want in the file, when you look at his content using an hex viewer the bytes 41 42 43 (in hex)?

Comment: "*it only writes one character*" - no, it does not.  It writes 10 bytes. Do not be confused by the fact the code is indexing into the 1st element of the array, that is just because `TStream.Write()` takes its 1st parameter as an untyped `var`, and you are using a dynamic array instead of a fixed array, so you have to dereference the array in order to pass in the correct memory address of the array data.

Comment: @fpiette well when i open the binary file using a hex editor and i search for the selected position there is a date example 21-01-2020 so i want to replace it by today's date . via a tedit.text or via a date time picker. or a function that returns to current system date and write directly to the selected offset the desired value.

Comment: @JuanMedina i'm still trying to figure out how to get the string converted to the desired hex value and write it directly to the bin file at the desired position (offset )

Comment: Again @coolric, on your code, you have no string to be inserted, hence you won't insert what you want on a specific location. Also, you are creating a file each time, so you will insert nothing into an empty file with an offset of the empty content of the file, so from any place you will be able to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no conversion required! Just write the string, according to your comment, you must write ansi string (one byte per character). For a date, a simple cast to AnsiString is enough. The compiler emit a warning because such as cast would not work as expected for accented character or Chineese, or so. I used a compiler directive to turn that warning off.

I have no more Delphi 10.1, but the code below should work with that old compiler.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Buffer     : AnsiString;
    FileName   : String;
    FileStream : TFileStream;
begin
    {$WARN IMPLICIT_STRING_CAST_LOSS OFF}
    Buffer     := String(FormatDateTime('MM-DD-YYYY', Now));
    FileName   := 'E:\Temp\file.bin';
    if not FileExists(FileName) then begin
        ShowMessage('File not found: "' + FileName + '"');
        Exit;
    end;

    FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite);
    try
        FileStream.Seek($15c20, soBeginning);
        FileStream.Write(Buffer[1], Length(Buffer));
    finally
        FileStream.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain it as best as I can as per the description and not taking the code provided into consideration, because it's missing key information.

**To convert a string to a byte array:**

```
byteArray := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('some string');
```

**To insert the byte array into a file having an offset:**

```
fileStream := System.IO.FileStream.Create('F:\test\file.bin', FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
fileStream.Seek($15c20, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fileStream.Write(byteArray,0,Length(byteArray));
fileStream.Close;
```

Comment: i'm using delphi berlin 10.1 , system.IO does not exist but there is System.IOUtils
which unit should i use to perform such action ?
also the first one also did not work to convert to byte array 
 Types incompatibles : 'Dynamic array' et 'System.TArray<System.Byte>'